# Observable.just() which returns Unit in Kotlin

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I have a piece of Observable which in the end either returns an error and retries or just returns onNext. I don't need anything in onNext, so this is just an `Observable<Unit>`.

Now the problem is that at the end of the chain I have to hit this onNext and I don't have anything other than good old `Observable.just()`. But I cannot return Observable.just(null) because it returns `Nothing?`, not `Unit`. I cannot return `Unit`, because it's not instantiable. Therefore I have `Observable.just(null).map{}`. It works, but looks ugly. Any idea for a better solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Observable.just(Unit)`. [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) itself is the single object of the type `Unit`.